# how to get the value of an array and match it to the window.locaton

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string-matching, location-href

I want to remove part of a string in an loop and then I have to check if its equal to window.location.

linkAdd= should return a array. but it looks like its return a string. So how do I check if there is a like on the website that is equal to the adresPath var? how do I create a var that contians all /123/1.php,/123/2.php,/123/3.php, and not just one /123/1.php? And then check /123/1.php is equal to the adresPath variable?

I have tried to remove the first part of the domain on every element. by loping true them. and doing .replace. but it seems not to return an array. for a clear explination check the code.

````
var adresPath = window.location.pathname; 
var link      = $('.menu-item>a');
var linkAdres = $('.menu-item>a').href;
var linkAdd   =  $('.menu-item>a').href.replace("http://bertconinx.com/","")
//link linkAdres and linkadd should be arrays. but when i try linkadd[i] it returns a letter of the string.

//ther are 19 a href in my code.


for(i = 0; i < link.length; i++){
    var linkAdd   = link[i].href.replace("http://bertconinx.com/","")
    };

> linkAdd= should return a array. but it looks like its return a string.
> So how do I check if there is a like on the website that is equal to
> the adresPath var? how do I create a var that contians all
> /123/1.php,/123/2.php,/123/3.php, and not just one /123/1.php? And
> then check /123/1.php is equal to the adresPath variable?


if(adresPath=linkAdd[i]){alert(happy happy it works!)};```

> linkAdd= should return a array. but it looks like its return a string.
> So how do I check if there is a like on the website that is equal to
> the adresPath var? how do I create a var that contians all
> /123/1.php,/123/2.php,/123/3.php, and not just one /123/1.php? And
> then check /123/1.php is equal to the adresPath variable?
> 
> error messegas are.. 
> 
> undefined when tying to return an object of the array I get the letter
> of the string. ex. link[9] retunrs "p" of php.




the html

<pre>

    <li id="menu-item-461" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">

        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">portriats</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-473" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
                        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">Disarray Body</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-617" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
                    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">#Girls</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>

<li id="menu-item-462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category current-post-ancestor current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current-post-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-461">

        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/category/portriats/">Item2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-412" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post current-menu-item menu-item-473">
                        <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/" aria-current="page">object1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-619" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post menu-item-617">
                    <a href="http://bertconinx.com/2019/09/16/girls/">Object2</a></li>
        </ul>
</li> </pre>
````

Comment: can you add a some lines of the links in the html part?

Comment: Can you please add html snippet ? So that the issue can be reproduced ?

Comment: please post a relevant portion of your HTML code

Comment: pasted in the html.

Comment: How about splitting adresPath into an array on comma and processing one by one?

adresPath.split(",")

Then you can match it to absolute or relative path...

Comment: adresPath is not an array. adresPath is the var where I need to check all a ellement agianst. and preform an action to the siblings and the parants. of .style.display = "block"; to the

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can do in plain javascript

```
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
const anchors = [];
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    anchors.push(links[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0]); 

}

const linkAddresses = [...anchors].map(anchor => anchor.href.replace("http://bertconinx.com/",""));
```

Now you will have an array like `["category/portriats/", "2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/", "2019/09/16/girls/", "category/portriats/", "2019/08/12/non-profit-profit/", "2019/09/16/girls/"]` in your `linkAddress` variable. Now you can iterate over this array and find if any of the links match with `addresPath`

```
linkAddresses.forEach(address => {
    if (address === adresPath) {
        // matches
    }
})
```